# Define a function in Excel VBA where it runs SQL query (selecting the given from function columns and rows)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database, odbc

I am fairly new to SQL and VBA. I want to create a function and then make it an add-in, where I will be able to select a range of ids and a range of column names and retrieve the data from an excel file (ADODB.Connection).
I have found some instructions here (https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-excel-workbook-as-database-using-odbc-source/?fbclid=IwAR3uaiUOCwDVNhM_gMbsPdHWFPodxL0EsIcTAeRh6Qu1GzLRjB4eW8QR9is); I have replicated and adjusted the code for my case. But I can't find a way to:

1. make it a public function.
2. adjust the SQL query for selecting the selected through the function ids (rows) and column names.

the code so far:

```
Public Function getData(id As Range, cols As Range)

Set ActiveC = Application.ActiveCell


Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Open "DSN=SumitODBC"
strQuery = "SELECT " & cols & " FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z500] where id = '" & id & "' "
Set resultSet = Connection.Execute(strQuery)
Do While Not resultSet.EOF
ActiveC.Value = resultSet.Fields("cols").Value

resultSet.movenext
Loop
resultSet.Close
End Function
```

A simplistic dataset:

[Data and what I want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9YGO.png)

Comment: The way you do that is `VLOOKUP` to that Excel file, not an SQL query.

Comment: Thanks Gserg. I am aware of vlookup, but my database is huge with many tables and is updated twice a day. What I have shown above is just a simplistic example. A custom function will be very convenient for me. thanks